# How can I validate JSON array value in postman?

Tags: postman, web-api-testing, postman-testcase

```
{
    "success": {
        "text": "successfully! deleted Records"
    }
}
```

Want to validate text value is "successfully! deleted Records"

I tried with this

```
pm.test("Your test name", function () {
    var jsonData = pm.response.json();

    pm.expect(jsonData[0].text).to.eql("successfully! deleted Records");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to retrieve data from a JSON object, not from an array. Hence, it should be as follows.

```
pm.test("Your test name", function () {
    var jsonData = pm.response.json();    
    pm.expect(jsonData.success.text).to.eql("successfully! deleted Records");
});
```